# angularjs: rescaling textbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to make an editable textbox like those in powerpoint and other presentation editors.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/5zVma/) is my feeble attempt.

I'm having trouble with the initial rescaling. To be concise, the first instant when I adjust the drag handle, the box does not scale to the correct height and width.

Any idea why is that so?

```
element.find('span').bind('mousedown', function(event) {
                console.log('resizing...');
                event.preventDefault();
                var domElement = element[0];

                var rect = domElement.getBoundingClientRect();
                startX = rect.left;
                startY = rect.bottom;
                console.log(startX + " " + startY);

                $document.bind('mousemove', resize);
                $document.bind('mouseup', mouseup2);
                event.cancelBubble = true;
            });


function resize(event) {

                var height = event.screenY - startY;
                var width = event.screenX - startX;
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.tb.height = height + 'px';
                    scope.tb.width = width + 'px';
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5zVma/1/) implementing this:

1. `tbW` and `tbH` hold the current box size (inital 200px x 100px):

   ```
   var tbW = 200,
       tbH = 100;

   scope.tb.width = tbW + 'px',
   scope.tb.height = tbH + 'px';
   ```
2. On mousedown startX and startY are assigned to the current mouse postion
3. In the resize function the delta of the mouse movement is calculated and added to the width and height of your `tbox`:

   ```
   tbH += event.screenY - startY;
   startY = event.screenY;
   tbW += event.screenX - startX;
   startX = event.screenX;
   scope.$apply(function () {
     scope.tb.height = tbH + 'px';
     scope.tb.width = tbW + 'px';
   });
   ```

Comment: Brilliant! Apologize for the late response. Thank you!